# What does ._[0] in args._[0] do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-arguments

I've been experimenting with some node code ( trying to build a small cli) and came across this underscore notation which is pretty foreign to me. Just from playing with the different arguments at the command line,

I realize that it's something like "extract" the first string to assign to "template" key, but I've never seen this before and can't quite find the documentation on this. Is this a native javascript/node thing?

```
import arg from 'arg';

function parseArgumentsIntoOptions(rawArgs) {
 const args = arg(
   {
     '--git': Boolean,
     '--yes': Boolean,
     '--install': Boolean,
     '-g': '--git',
     '-y': '--yes',
     '-i': '--install',
   },
   {
     argv: rawArgs.slice(2),
   }
 );
 return {
   skipPrompts: args['--yes'] || false,
   git: args['--git'] || false,
   template: args._[0],                                // <<<<< Right here
   runInstall: args['--install'] || false,
 };
}
```

I don't have lodash or underscore installed.
Taken from this [awesome tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/how-to-build-a-cli-with-node-js).

Comment: I think the underscore it the name of a property. This propety is an array. The object `args = { '_': [] }` would fit.

Comment: This is not related to Node.js in any way. `args` is the value returned by the `arg()` function (that is not a standard Node.js function but probable an external dependency). A quick look on npmjs.com reveals its possible source to be https://www.npmjs.com/package/arg

Comment: That tutorial installs a library called `arg`. Documentation is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/arg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of the [`arg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/arg) library:

> All parameters that aren't consumed by options (commonly referred to as "extra" parameters) are added to `result._`, which is always an array (even if no extra parameters are passed, in which case an empty array is returned).

So `args._[0]` is the first extra parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I did't hit `npm arg` library the first time that is indeed my *only* imported module here because i googled `node arg` for some reason.

The underscore is actually just the "container" for the rest of the arguments that are unused by any of the keys you specified:

> Parameters that aren't consumed by options (commonly referred to as "extra" parameters) are added to `result._`